# Finiteness of the Supremum of Inner Product of Two Finite Sum Positive Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, linear-programming, inner-products, quadratic-programming

Let $$A = \Big\{(a_1,a_2,\dots)\ \Big|\ a_i\ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=1\Big\},$$ $$v(x)=\sup\left(\bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ib_i\ \bigg|\ (a_i)_{i=1}^\infty,\, (b_i)_{i=1}^\infty \in A,\,\sup\limits_{i\in \mathbf N} a_ib_i =x\bigg\}\right).$$ Certainly $v$ is an increasing function. Is $v(x)$ finite for every $x$? Is it achievable? Does $v(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\Big( \sum_i a_ib_i\Big)^2 &= \Big(\sum_i (a_ib_i)^\frac{1}{2}a_i^\frac{1}{2}b_i^\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2 \\
&\le \sup\limits_i (a_ib_i)\Big(\sum_i a_i^\frac{1}{2}b_i^\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2 \\
&\le \sup\limits_i (a_ib_i)\sum_i a_i\sum_ib_i.
\end{align}